# Bootstrap 4 cards with the_post_thumbnail() images Stretch to fit using wordpress?

Tags: php, image, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to stretch feature images to fit bootstrap cards. The cards align and respond correctly, but the images go all over the place.

```
    <section class="container"><!-- container - 3 --><p class="text-white">.</p>
        <div class="row">
            <article class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 mb-4 ">
                <div class="card">
                    <?php  if(have_posts()) : ?>
                    <?php $i = 4; while (have_posts() && $i < 5) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'small','style=max-width:150%;height:auto;'); ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                            <!-- <a href="<?php //the_permalink(); ?>"> -->
                            <div class="sub-Article text-center card-title"><?php the_title();?>
                            <!-- </a> -->
                    <p>Article - <span class="font-weight-normal small"><?php the_time('F j, Y g:i:a');?></span></div>
                            <!-- <p class="Main-Article"><?php //the_title(); ?></p> -->
                            <!-- <a class="button btn-primary btn-lg text-left" href="<?php //the_permalink(); ?>">
                             Selengkapnya ></a></span> -->
                    <?php $i++;  endwhile; ?>
                    <?php  else : ?>
                    <?php  echo wpautop('Sorry no posts were found'); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </article>
        </row>
     </section>
```

Above is an example of one of a cards from index.php. I've used very little css as I want to see if it's possible to arrange everything just using bootstrap. All the css does is add a frosty front over the image with the title and dates.

```
.sub-Article{
    margin-top:-160px;
    background-color:white;
    opacity:0.5;
    padding: 30px 30px 35px 30px
}
```

Ironically, the feature image displayed in Wordpress's backend cms, logged in a wp-admin, works perfectly!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using <img> tags. They don't work with the_post_thumbnail(). I tried using img-fluid through a div, but it had no effect

Comment: You need to post your output HTML because this has nothing to do with PHP and PHP code is useless for debugging an issue of this nature.

Comment: How is that going to help. I can fix the the html. Like I said, I've already written a perfect good working one with standard html. It's how to get the image to cover the background of a card when I'm bringing it in dynamically that I need to find out. I'll work it out myself...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know that this shouldn't work, but it does! After playing around with the image thing, I discovered that just adding `<img class="style"` without having to close the tags, works!

```
<img class="style"<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
```

Then feel free to give it whatever style you like :)